# firefox could not initialize security component

Tags: firefox, user-profiles, ubuntu-12.04

One day I decided to have a separate instance of firefox running alone side my current instance - not the private browsing fashion. I knew profiles were the way to do it. So I did something like this in the shell:

```
firefox -p user1 -no-remote
```

...and this problem seems to surface. And each time I start firefox I get the following alert.

[image]

The problem I face is all the cookies, sites, etc which were associated with my default profile is somehow gone. I can workaround this; I simply type this in the shell:

```
firefox -p default
```

But I want my old behavior back.

Comment: Does the data for your old profile exist on your computer?

Comment: yes. it still does exist.